# Get same Google Billing SKU's for alterantive app package names

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, google-pay, play-billing-library

In our app we have 2 app **naming schemas**: `com.my.app` for release builds, and `com.my.app.debug`, for, well, debugging.
This is setup this way, so we can separate analytics on Firebase - so debug crashes don't pollute our productions insights.

In comes **Android Billing**. In our Play store account, we have uploaded our productions build `.aab` (`com.my.app`), and set-up some in-app subscriptions. I'll add that we are still in the pre-prod stage.

Problem is- **we don't get any `SKU`s in *debug* build, since the package signature is different than the one configured in, and up-loaded to Play Store console**.

The questions is- Is there a way to integrate/test our  **production** Android Billing products against our **debug** build, other than creating a new `app` with the `debug` package name?

Answer (score 2):

No, different package means different app and therefore different in-app products that cannot be shared with another app.

The strange thing is that you have made a different app for debugging when android studio and other IDEs can work in debug mode or release mode without changing project.

Comment: Thanks @Lluis Felisart, I assumed as much. As for your question - we add a suffix to the debug package name to differentiate it in Firebase. the IDE doesn't care